# How can I pause code at vscode breakpoints when running pytest from the terminal?

Tags: pytest, vscode-debugger

I would like to run some unit tests in debug mode. I would like to run them from the console to replicate the behavior below:

[image]

[image]

I understand I can open up `pdb` automatically with `pytest --trace`. What I would prefer to do instead is mimic the behavior of vscode point and click, where running the test stops at a break point set in the ide. Is that possible to do?